# How to use my authentication filter with Websocket for Cometd deployed in Jetty?

Tags: authentication, websocket, jetty, cometd

I am using Cometd 3.0.1 with jetty 9.2.3 using JSR 356 based websocket implementation (and not jetty's own websocket implementation).

I have added some auth filters which basically ask for authentication headers from request. But as websocket upgrade happen as a part of websocketupgrade filter, is there a way to make authentication work here?

Answer (score 0):

Authenticating via a Filter is the wrong way to accomplish authentication.

**Correct Solution:**

The servlet spec expects you to setup and configure the the authentication and authorization layers of your application using the servlet techniques of both the container and the application metadata (`WEB-INF/web.xml`)

This means you setup a the container side security, either using the Jetty container specific `LoginService`, or using a JAAS spec configuration.  Then you reference your security realms in your `WEB-INF/web.xml` and use them.  If you have something custom, then you can hook into the `LoginService` of your choice (even a custom one) and manage it accordingly.

JAAS and LoginService Authentication and Authorization is applied before all filters and servlets.

In this scenario, you'll have access to the authentication information during the upgrade process, in particular during the [`ServerEndpointConfig.Configurator.modifyHandshake()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/websocket/server/ServerEndpointConfig.Configurator.html#modifyHandshake(javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpointConfig,%20javax.websocket.server.HandshakeRequest,%20javax.websocket.HandshakeResponse))

**Ugly Hack Solution:**

Add the `org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.WebSocketUpgradeFilter` to your `WEB-INF/web.xml` manually.

This then leaves it up to you to attempt to get your authentication filter to exist before this `WebSocketUpgradeFilter` in 100% of use cases.

> Caution: filter execution ordering is **not** part of the servlet spec.  Be careful with this, as it might seem to be working on your dev machine and then suddenly not work in QA or production.  Simply because the Set of filters in the metadata will have a different order in it.

Notes:

- Path Spec must be `/*`
- Async Supported must be `true`
- Dispatcher Types must be `REQUEST` only.
- **Do not set** the `contextAttributeKey` for that filter
- All other WebSocketUpgradeFilter init-params are invalid for JSR-356 use (they are overridden by the various JSR-356 endpoint configurations)

Comment: Is there an example of this correct solution using a custom login service somewhere?