# How do I send a 401 unauthorized from a javax.websocket server

Tags: java, authentication, websocket, jetty

I have WebSocket server running on Jetty 9.3.6 implemented using `javax.websocket.server` API. In my Jetty webapp, I do some form of authorization using HTTP headers (using `modifyHanshake ()`), and if it authenticates, everything is OK and I go on with WebSocket messaging between server and client. However, when the authentication does not go through, I would like to return a HTTP 401 Unauthorized. How do I do this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why not use a Servlet Filter instead? This way, the authentication can be done before the communication ever even gets to your websocket code.

Comment: @rmlan not going to work reliably as a filter, as upgrade is often the FIRST thing in the servlet chain that is executed.   However if you do it as a custom security layer (which occurs before the servlet chain) then it could work.

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt: Any clues as to how to implement a custom security layer based solution for this? Thanks for taking the time!

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt: Never mind, I found your answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30068095/how-to-use-my-authentication-filter-with-websocket-for-cometd-deployed-in-jetty?rq=1 and http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/configuring-security-authentication.html. Please let me know if that is what you meant. Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately Servlet filters are not applied before Websocket upgrade with Jetty. See here for details: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25997240/281469